# Ensure enum name uniqueness in C without adding long prefix

Tags: c, enums, c99

I find myself always appending the name of the enum, to its values, because else I often have conflicts with other enums, for example:

```
typedef enum
{
    A_ONE,
    A_TWO,
} A;

typedef enum
{
    B_ONE,
    B_TWO,
} B;
```

Is there a nicer way to do this in C?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2161940/335858 (short answer is "no").

Comment: Another example of the problem: `enum fruit { orange, apple, banana }; enum color { red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not.  C++ has namespaces, or enums existing in classes (IIRC), but C is extremely primitive in this regard.

Answer (score -1):

It is your own decision, but you can use the #define directive

`#define WHAT_EVER TO_BE_REPLACED`

Defines will be replaced from the `WHAT_EVER` in your code with `TO_BE_REPLACED`.

After your preprocessor run throw your code, all will be replaced.

Comment: How does that address the issue in the question?